# html : detect overflow and change font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css

i search solution to detect overflows in the css-class .entry.title,
and when detect take some css to reduce the font-size.

example: css before detection:

```
.entry-title {
font-size: 1.42em;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

css after detection:

```
.entry-title {
font-size: calc(1.42em * 0.95);
white-space: inherit;
overflow: inherit;
text-overflow: inherit;
}
```

I think this could be done with javascript but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the text body of an object of such a class is on a single line, this problem will be easy.
However, it is very difficult to dynamically adjust the font size to eliminate overflow when there are multiple lines of text and complex elements in it.
This is because many style factors affect the overflow of the object, in addition to the font size of the text, and calculating them all is very time-consuming.
To implement response performance related to font size, it is best to use @media{}.
For example:

```
.entry-title{
    font-size: 16px;
}
    
@media(max-width: 1024px){
    .entry-title{
        font-size: 14px;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to detect element is overflow, this is a demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sun-ouotsz?file=/src/styles.css